# Rename Dynamics CRM organization name

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I was confronted with this problem: We use the company name as a name of the organization of a dynamics crm instance. the name of the company has changed and the organization name need to be updated.

How to rename Microsoft Dynamics crm **organization name** in the online/on-premise version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On-premise, you should use **Deployment manager** ([Step by Step here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/darrenliu/archive/2013/09/21/change-crm-organization-display-name.aspx))
- Online, the steps are :

  > 1. Sign into https://portal.microsoftonline.com/
  > 2. Admin Menu > CRM
  > 3. Select Organization > Edit Settings
  > 4. Change the name/URL